# How to compare zero using cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am trying to do this `user.abc_id.should == 0` and it error out saying

```
expected: 0
 got: "0" (using ==) (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

Comment: The issue is string vs number. Unfortunately you provide zero context for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is as Dave said in the comment is string vs. number. If you [look at the rspec documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/equality-matchers) you will see

```
 a == b # object equivalence - a and b have the same value with type conversions
```

a `string object` and `integer object` are **not equivalent**.

So you may try something like

```
a.eql?(b) # object equivalence - a and b have the same value
```

In your case this may work

```
user.abc_id.should eql(0)
```